# Is there any alternative of window.showModalDialog & window.open

Tags: javascript

I want to use popup window in my Project with customize flavor like address bar don't display 
return value, customize close button finally it will be look like :

[image]

Comment: What you want to do is dynamically create (or unhide) a div element that will sit above the rest of the page so that the user can't click on the elements behind. You can get that shading effect at the edges with appropriate CSS settings. It's not really another window, it just looks that way to the user...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you should be using some kind of custom made popups and dialogue like

```
http://umairj.com/27/how-to-create-simple-modal-dialogue-using-jquery/ 
http://www.jquery4u.com/windows/14-jquery-modal-dialog-boxes/
```